# Java equals function not working correctly

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I know this question is asked several times on stackOverflow. But still I am not able to get ***equals*** function for two strings to work correctly.

Here's what I am doing and where I am facing problem. 
I am calling AsyncTask method in a following manner

```
String ServerResponse = realTimeTask.execute("http://www.xyz.co/tests/ems/realtimequery.php?q="+ newString).get();
```

The newString variable is an dynamic variable that I fetch from the Navigation Drawer that I am using in my app.

The String variable newString can have 7 different values based on the item clicked in the navigation drawer.

What I want to do is a simple string to string comparison between my dynamic variable newString and a static variable let's say

```
String aVar = "Stenter";
```

Now I tried using comparison following way

```
if (newString.equals(aVar)) {
                System.out.println("This is a stenter");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("This is not a stenter");
            }
```

But no luck, everytime I run this condition with newString also equals to Stenter. I get the result in the else part.

Could someone point me where I am going wrong over here? Kindly don't downvote this question, Since I have looked everywhere over internet and then posted my question after waiting and trying out for a day.

Thanks in advance!

-----------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------
Here's the code which shall give an idea on how I declare newString

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_machine_details);

        String newString;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                newString= null;
            } else {
                newString= extras.getString("keyName");
                Toast.makeText(this, newString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("keyName");
            Toast.makeText(this, newString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();


        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        RealTimeTask realTimeTask = new RealTimeTask();
        try {
           String ServerResponse = realTimeTask.execute("http://www.xyz.co/tests/ems/realtimequery.php?q="+ newString).get();


            String aVar = "Stenter";
            System.out.println(newString);

            newString.trim();

            if (newString.equalsIgnoreCase(aVar)) {
                System.out.println("This is a stenter");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("This is not a stenter");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The if condition is in the try catch block after a call to asyncTask method.

Comment: strange case .Try with `if (newString.matches(aVar))`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: I tried your solution, does not work for me. I even tried to print newString value and it's exactly same as that of aVar i.e., "Stenter"

Comment: Can you show where you declare `newString` and set its value?

Comment: Please show how are you fetching newString? and further more, please print the newString value to console and then show us

Comment: Can you please try by hard-coding value in newString just before if loop?
Just to verify that newString doesn't contain any other characters.

Comment: @yshavit: I have edited the question to show the full code. And I even tried printing newString value which is equal to Stenter after clicking on Stenter in my navigation drawer

Comment: It should be `newString = newString.trim();`

Comment: @Suyash: when I hardcode the value of newString before if loop with the value equal to Stenter, same as aVar. The condition runs perfectly alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be case is not matchingyou can try

```
1) if (newString.matches(aVar)){
}
```

or

```
2) if (newString.equalsIgnoreCase(aVar)){
}
```

or

try with `newString.trim()` then compare

trim() method removes spaces after and before the variable like if

```
String s="abc ";   //space at last
```

s.trim() will remove last space and return `"abc"`

Comment: Not working, I had tried this examples before as well and tried again. No success. Still getting the else part.

Comment: Okay so newString.trim() worked for me. It's just that I didn't used it properly in my code. thanks to you and Titus who commented the correction. But could someone explain me why it worked so with .trim(). What exactly it means? I am new to java. thanks!

Comment: trim() removes extra spaces from the start and end of the string.Your string might be like "  Stenter  " instead of "Stenter". 
You should have checked this before posting such question here.